# It is possible to make the grey lines between this divs?

Tags: html, css, online-store

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsAEX.png

I'm trying to do this e store only using a `1140px` system grid. Is that possible or better use a framework like Foundation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible using css3 border property , or you can use bootstrap 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Comment: put an id at all divs?

Comment: @alexkurban  put class , and it possible using css class  `  .border-box{ border:1px solid #CCCCCC;  }   .most-left{ border-right:0px;  }   .most-right{ border-left:0px }`   and html like this ` <ul><li class="border-box most-left"></li><li class="border-box"></li><li class="border-box"></li><li class="border-box most-right"></li></ul>`